# Compare three enums in swift

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui

I have `enum ColorValue` with three cases and I have three variables now How do I compare these three  variables has same enum values?

Code:

```
enum ColorValue {
 case red
 case blue
 case green
}
var arrayOfCards : Array<Card>

struct Card {
  var color : ColorValue
}
```

now

I want to do this

```
if arrayOfCards[0].color == arrayOfCards[1].color == arrayOfCards[2].color {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Does `arrayOfCards` include any elements but those 3?

Comment: I tried it but it gave me error @Roope

Comment: arrayfCards include only three cards any given time @user28434

Comment: This is the error - Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '(ColorValue, ColorValue)' operands

Comment: if (arrayOfCards[0].color == arrayOfCards[1].color) &&  (arrayOfCards[0].color == arrayOfCards[2].color) {
          // do something
       }